# Model Binding in Multiple Component to a single EditForm by Blazor Server

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I have a large form so need to split into several component and present in several tab view. But I getting stack to bind EditForm model in other components. my tries is as below but getting

**EditForm requires a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, but not both**

```
<EditForm Model="@model">
    <BSTabGroup>
        <BSTabList>
            <BSTab>
                <BSTabLabel>General Info</BSTabLabel>
                <BSTabContent>
                    <GeneralInfo generalInfoModel ="@model"></GeneralInfo>
                </BSTabContent>
            </BSTab>
        </BSTabList>
        <BSTabSelectedContent />
    </BSTabGroup>
</EditForm>
@code {public Account model{ get; set; } }

<FbInputText Id="txtAcName" ConfigOption="2" MaxLength="5" Label="Account" @bind-Value="@generalInfoModel .prop" ></FbInputText>
@code { [Parameter] public Account generalInfoModel { get; set; } }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure your model is not null.